# Push a local project to new gitlab repo

Tags: git, gitlab, push

I have a local git project that contains some branches (master & others)
i would like to push it to a new gitlab repo
so:
1. I created a new gitlab repo with:

> Initial commit

then i run

`git commit -am "some message"
git add remote gitlab <url-to-repo.git>
git push gitlab master`

it dosent work and shows:

> ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
>
> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.com/myName/myrepo.git                                                                                                        '
>
> hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
>
> hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
>
> hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
>
> hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
>
> hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

when i tried:
`git push gitlab master -f`
it dosent work also, and get:

> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.com/myName/myrepo.git

and the same result if i add:
`--force` or `-f` option

Comment: See what git tries to tell you : you need to pull (to get the most recent changes on remote master) before pushing onto it. Pushing "harder" (with --force) is not a solution as git is a very stubborn animal ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just follow git advices - first, try to execute `git pull` -> it'll merge origin with local branches -> and then try `git push`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:
It's to create an empty gitlab repo  (
( The error was that the last time i initialized it with README)

it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute **"git fetch"**, and check if you are on the master branch.

Navigate to the branch and try **git pull** on here, and move to the origin branch and try git **pull again**.

The next step is try to **push** your local changes.